# How do I link my first check box with the appropriate row

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, row, cell

I'm attempting to write a vba that automatically links checkboxes to the appropriate rows. I wrote the following

```
Sub LinkChecklist()

Dim chk As CheckBox

For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    chk.LinkedCell = chk.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).Address
Next

End Sub
```

however when I run the code, the first checkbox which starts on row 2 col F, links to row 1 col G when it should be linking to row 2. This makes it so that some of the checkboxes below it link to the wrong cells also. Any tips on how to resolve that issue?

Also, would appreciate any tips on making sure that each row contains only one check box. As you can see in the image, the more text there is in a cell, the more the checkboxes get messed up. Is there any way to make it so that each row, no matter how large or small it gets, contains only one  checkbox?

Thanks

[image: image of checkboxes]

Comment: Positioning checkboxes on a specific row is tricky and you can easily end up with checkboxes whose TopLeftCell is actually on the row above...   Personally I would avoid using checkboxes like this, for the reasons you outline...

Comment: Are you sure that first check box "starts on row 2 col F"? Please, try adding such a line before the one existing in the iteration: `Debug.print chk.TopLeftCell.address, chk.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).address:Stop`. When code stops on that line, press `F8` and run it line by line, seeing if there are discrepancies between the two cell addresses and see the checkbox from the iteration where they  belong to.

Comment: thank you @FaneDuru for your suggestion. would your line of code go right before "Next" in my code ? I am struggling a bit to understanding your explanation

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this is something that needs to work so everyone in the office can use.

Comment: Data validation with a yes/no list would be more reliable

Comment: You can place it where you say. I was suggesting placing it above the line `chk.LinkedCell = chk.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).Address`, to see which check box is processed after seeing the return in Immediate Window. But, it may also work as you said.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use checkboxes then it's best to use code to add them and set the properties.
For example:

```vb
'add checkboxes and link cell one column over
Sub SetUpChecks()
    Dim c As Range, cb
    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        Set cb = Selection.Worksheet.CheckBoxes.Add(c.Left + 1, c.Top + 1, 10, 10)
        cb.Placement = xlMove                   'move with cell
        cb.Caption = ""                         'no caption
        cb.LinkedCell = c.Offset(0, 1).Address  'linked cell
    Next c
End Sub
```

You could also write some code (triggered by the sheet activate event for example) which would loop over any existing checkboxes and make sure they're positioned correctly, by checking the `LinkedCell` property and re-positioning if needed.

Something like this maybe:

```vb
Sub RepositionCheckboxes()
    Dim cb, c As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each cb In ws.CheckBoxes
        If cb.LinkedCell <> "" Then
            Set c = ws.Range(cb.LinkedCell).Offset(0, -1) 'one cell to the left of the linked cell
            cb.Top = c.Top + 1
            cb.Left = c.Left + 1
        End If
    Next cb
End Sub
```